# Is it possible to store an image to dropbox datastore via datastore API?

Tags: android, dropbox

I take a picture and want to save it in the datastore along with the date of the picture. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can save any binary data into datastore, but the size of individual images are limited to 100kb.

Source: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/tutorial/android in "Field types":

> Bytes (byte[]) – Arbitrary data, which is treated as binary, such as thumbnail images or compressed data. Individual records can be up to 100KB, which limits the size of the blob. If you want to store larger files, you should use the Sync API and reference the paths to those files in your records.

Comment: Adding on to @Tsotne's response, for bigger chunks of data, I'd recommend actually using files to store them. You can then store the path to the file in the datastore to maintain the link between them. (But note that a user might rename a file.)